# Power associative magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

I’m looking for a magma with specific properties:
Requirements:
1.Power Associative(of course, I want it to not be alternative or similar).
2.Invertibility and identity element.
Preferences(In order of priority):
1.finite.
2.well known and or with a recognizabled name.
3.Simple to explain and construct.

When I first searched it online, I’ve found the sedenenions and the similar, which were way too complex for my wanting.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it has a name, but here's a three element example (which is even commutative and has *unique* inverses) - note that since every two-element magma with an identity is alternative, this is the smallest example possible. (See the bottom of this answer for a more "symmetric" example in which however inverses are not unique.)

The elements of our magma $M$ are $e,x,y$. Unsurprisingly $e$ will be the identity; the rest of our multiplication table is given by $$xx=e, yy=e, xy=yx=x.$$ (I'm using concatenation for the magma operation for simplicity).

We trivially have an identity and unique inverses, and left alternativity fails since $$(xx)y=ey=y\color{red}{\not=}e=xx=x(xy)$$ (right alternativity fails similarly). To see that $M$ is power associative, simply note that each element of $M$ generates a fully associative submagma. And to top it off, $M$ is commmutative, which we didn't even ask for initially.

---

Let me say a bit about the general idea behind this answer. This was the following, especially the first bulletpoint:

> Suppose we have a magma $M$ and submagmas $A_i$ ($i\in I$) such that $M=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. Then:
>
> - If each $A_i$ is associative, $M$ is power-associative.
> - If there is some $e\in\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ which each $A_i$ thinks is the identity element then $e$ is in fact the identity in $M$.
> - If the above bulletpoint holds and additionally each $A_i$ has inverses, then $M$ has inverses - and the inverse of an element of $A_i$ in the sense of $M$ is the inverse of that element in the sense of $A_i$.

This suggests a general way to build power associative magmas with identities and inverses. What we've done above is do this with two "components," each of which is in fact a group - namely, the "$x$-part" and "$y$-part" are both copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. After determining our "components," and deciding how exactly they overlap (we want them to have a common identity, and for simplicity we might as well make them *only* have their identity elements in common), all we have to do is determine how elements from different "components" multiply.

But now we're almost home free: **any** decision we make here will give us a magma which is power associative and has an identity and inverses. So we just play around a bit and find a choice which makes things nice.

In a bit more detail, having decided to build a magma by "gluing two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ together at the identity," we have two decisions to make (letting $x$ and $y$ be the non-identity elements of our magma):

- Which of $x,y,e$ is $xy$?
- Which of $x,y,e$ is $yx$?

The most obvious alternative (hehe) to what we've done above is to declare $xy=yx=e$. The resulting magma is more "symmetric" - the map switching $x$ and $y$ is a magma automorphism - and is still a commutative power associative non-alternative magma with identity and inverses; however, it does not have *unique* inverses.